# Why are elements null in jquery, yet exist with document.getelementbyid()

Tags: asp.net, jquery, gridview, checkbox

I"m trying to attached some jquery to checkboxes in a gridview, using `document.ready`:

```
  $(document).ready(function()
  { 
       var chkBox= document.getElementById("gvTimeSheet_ctl01_chkAll1");
       //I can alert chkBox.id, element exists

       var name = $("input[name='gvTimeSheet$ctl01$chkAll1']");
       //Here, when I alert the id, I get a null

       var ID = $("#gvTimeSheet_ctl01_chkAll1");
      //Here, when I alert the id, I get a null

       var withClass = $(".chkAll1Class");
       //Here, when I alert the id, I get a null

       var withClass2 = $(".Bill1");
       //Here, when I alert the id, I get a null

       //This line causes the browswer to crash and gives me the following error
       //Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'null' is null or not an object
       $("#gvTimeSheet_ctl01_chkAll1").click(function()           
       {
           var checked_status = this.checked;
           $("input[class=Bill1]").each(function()
           {
           this.checked = checked_status;
           });

       });

    });*/
```

So, why are any attempts at finding an object null in jquery, yet exist in regular javascript within the same method?  What am I missing here.  I have the jquery js files brought in in a script tag directly above this method.  I just can't seem to find any objects on this page with jquery.  On other pages, I can.

Comment: Are you using any other Javascript libraries?

Comment: Can you post the generated HTML source? Maybe publish a sandbox at http://jsbin.com/ would help understand.

Answer (score 2):

Objects that result from a jQuery selector are actually wrappers around a DOM object, so you don't access it the same as a DOM object.

If you're alerting just "name.id", from your first example above, there won't be any such property on the jQuery wrapper.  Try alerting your ID as follows:

```
alert(name.attr("id"));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var val = $("input:radio[name$='rdoselect']:checked").val();           
if (val == 1) {            
    $('[id$=divDate]').attr('disabled', true);                 
}else {             
    $('[id$=divDate]').attr('disabled', false);
}
```

Comment: The question begins with "Why are". Code is great for explaining how, but this doesn't seem to explain why.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var ID = $("#gvTimeSheet_ctl01_chkAll1");
```

This returns a jQuery object, not an ID. ID.id would also be undefined. To get the ID, you need:

```
var ID = $("#gvTimeSheet_ctl01_chkAll1").attr("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the page you're adding this code to already include the Prototype JavaScript library?

jQuery's "$" method never returns null, so this shouldn't be a problem:

```
// This line causes the browswer to crash and gives me the following error
// Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'null' is null or not an object
$("#gvTimeSheet_ctl01_chkAll1").click(function() { .... });
```

All the comments about needing to use `.attr('id')` still stand (though I prefer `$('#whatever')[0].id` myself.)